# A problem about the return value of C function

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I use ctypes to call C functions in Python with dll.

In c:

```c
typedef struct StructPointerTest* StructPointer;
struct StructPointerTest {
    int x;
    int y;
    int* z;
};

StructPointer testy() {
    StructPointer p = (StructPointer)malloc(sizeof(struct StructPointerTest));
    int d []={345,6867,45677};
    int* h=d;
    p->x = 101;
    p->y = 1029;
    p->z = h;
    return p;
}
```

In python:

```py
class StructPointer(ctypes.Structure):
        pass
StructPointer._fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_int),
                          ('y', ctypes.c_int),
                          ('z', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)),
                          ('next', ctypes.POINTER(StructPointer))]

dll.testy.restype = ctypes.POINTER(StructPointer)
p = dll.testy()
print(p.contents.x)
print(p.contents.y)
print(p.contents.z[0])
```

The first two output the correct value, but the value of the third pointer type is always wrong.

Comment: The variable `d` is a *local* variable inside the `testy` function. Once the function returns, it will be the end of the life-time for `d`, and any pointers you have to it will become immediately invalid.

Comment: Furthermore, your structure definition in the Python code doesn't match the actual structure in the C source.

Comment: How can I get the variable pointer in the function without copying the variable

Comment: You can't. Once the function returns the local variables cease to exist. You could perhaps solve it by making `d` a `static` local variable, whose life-time will be the whole program. But then all calls to `testy` would have only the one single variable `d`, any modification of the elements will be "global".

Comment: Thank you for your help. In an example, this function can get the variable value in the function. What is the difference between the two?

```
float* pointer_function(int* a, int n)
{
 float* p, * q;
 q = p = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 4);
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
  *p++ = i;
 }
 return q;
}
```

Comment: Memory you allocate from the heap (with e.g. `malloc`) will have a life-time until you pass the pointer to `free`.

Comment: I am a beginner of C, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments mention, the `d` array is a local variable so it is no longer available when the function returns.  Instead, that array should be allocated as well:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

typedef struct StructTest {
    int x;
    int y;
    int* z;
} StructTest;

API StructTest* get_struct() {
    StructTest* p = malloc(sizeof(StructTest));
    // int d []={345,6867,45677};  // local variable, destroyed when function returns so wrong
    p->x = 101;
    p->y = 1029;
    p->z = malloc(3 * sizeof(int)); // allocate array of 3 integers instead
    p->z[0] = 1;
    p->z[1] = 2;
    p->z[2] = 3;
    return p;
}

// Cleanup heap-allocated structure
API void free_struct(StructTest* p) {
    free(p->z);
    free(p);
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

class TestStruct(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('x', ct.c_int),
                ('y', ct.c_int),
                ('z', ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)))
    # Good habit: define how a class can print itself.
    # Also note string slicing is the way to access a pointer to array.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'TestStruct(x={self.x}, y={self.y}, z={self.z[:3]})'

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
# Good habit: declare all argument types and return types.
dll.get_struct.argtypes = ()
dll.get_struct.restype = ct.POINTER(TestStruct)
dll.free_struct.argtypes = ct.POINTER(TestStruct),
dll.free_struct.restype = None

p = dll.get_struct()
print(p.contents)
dll.free_struct(p)
```

Output:

```
TestStruct(x=101, y=1029, z=[1, 2, 3])
```